# Use macro to search table in Word to find specific string in a cell and then set typography on another cell in the same row

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with a table of 3 columns and an unknown number of rows and 
I need a macro that can search for the string "Sum" in column 1.

If an exact match is found the macro must set the typography of the two remaining cells in the row to two different typographies from Word and also delete the string "Sum" in cell 1.

The table can contain many instances of the string "sum" but they wil alwaye be in the first column.

The code I have tried, and I apologize for my lack of coding skills, but I have only been doing this for at week, works fine until the first instance of "sum" and then just quits.

I am using this code:

```
Sub FindSum() 

Dim oTbl As Table  
Dim oRow As Row 

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
            Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Sum", ReplaceWith:=""
            If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
                Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
                Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Titel")
                Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
                Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Citat")
            End If
        Next
    Next 
End Sub
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: single-step the code by using the F8 key on the keyboard (press multiple times) .... resize the editor window and the document so that you can see both.  .... that should let you know how the program flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this appears to work

ignores "Sum" outside of tables

tested with two tables

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindSum()

    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim stT As Long, enT As Long
    Dim stS As Long, enS As Long

    With Selection.Find             ' the settings remain until changed
        .Text = "Sum"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

        oTbl.Columns(1).Select                        ' not sure if this is required

        Do While Selection.Find.Execute

            stT = oTbl.Range.Start                    ' table range
            enT = oTbl.Range.End

            stS = Selection.Range.Start               ' found text range
            enS = Selection.Range.End

            If stS < stT Or enS > enT Then Exit Do    ' text found inside table ???

            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.Style = wdStyleTitle            ' original code was invalid
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.Style = wdStyleHeading3
        Loop
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next
End Sub
```