# Macro to find in Word table for specific string in a cell and move x cell left, check isnumeric then set typography on down x cell in the same column

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have below macro (modified base to suit expected result from [Use macro to search table in Word to find specific string in a cell and then set typography on another cell in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856136/use-macro-to-search-table-in-word-to-find-specific-string-in-a-cell-and-then-set?rq=1)).

I have a Word document with a table of variable columns (first 3 columns mixed width) and an unknown number of rows and I need a macro that can search for the string "Mean" in column 3. Current macro is for column 6 only. Expected from column 5 to last column.

If an exact match is found the macro move selection to column 6 (moving 3 cell left). Check the string is strictly numerical or not (having number followed by * or ** or ***). If is numerical then selection move 3 unit and replace string “-----“.

The current macro replace all string to “-----“ even string having non numerical string.

In short description, search “mean” then move left then check string is numerical or not. If numerical then do 3 unit down and replace with “-----“ else no change. It like L shape moving and replacing.

I am not able to check in between string is numerical or not and then replacement. I have try to include `regexp.Pattern = "^[0-9]+$"` checking but skipping that code.

Current macro is for column 6 only. Expected from column 5 to last column.

[image: Before] [image: After running macro] [image: Expected]

```
Sub FindMeanReplace()
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim stT As Long, enT As Long
    Dim stS As Long, enS As Long
    Dim regexp

    With Selection.Find             ' the settings remain until changed
        .Text = "Mean"
        .Replacement.Text = "Mean"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

        oTbl.Columns.Select                        ' not sure if this is required

        Do While Selection.Find.Execute

            stT = oTbl.Range.Start                    ' table range
            enT = oTbl.Range.End

            stS = Selection.Range.Start               ' found text range
            enS = Selection.Range.End

            If stS < stT Or enS > enT Then Exit Do    ' text found inside table ???

            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell

            'Set regexp = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")


            'regexp.Pattern = "[0-9]+$"  'not strictly return numbers
            'regexp.Pattern = "^[0-9]+$" 'strictly numeric


            Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3

            Selection.Delete ' = "--"

            Selection.Text = "-----"

        Loop
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Long, c As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Mean"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      r = .Cells(1).RowIndex
      c = .Cells(1).ColumnIndex
      With .Tables(1)
        If IsNumeric(Split(.Cell(r, c + 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)) Then .Cell(r + 3, c + 1).Range.Text = "--"
        If IsNumeric(Split(.Cell(r, c + 2).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)) Then .Cell(r + 3, c + 2).Range.Text = "--"
        If IsNumeric(Split(.Cell(r, c + 3).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)) Then .Cell(r + 3, c + 3).Range.Text = "--"
        If IsNumeric(Split(.Cell(r, c + 4).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)) Then .Cell(r + 3, c + 4).Range.Text = "--"
      End With
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```